# Which api/sdk is easy and useful in fetching images from account/page in Android platform?

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a project in which my activity fetches image from a account to my layout file Which api/sdk is easy and useful in fetching images from account/page in Android platform? 
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by account but Picasso is a great library for downloading and displaying images: http://square.github.io/picasso/

Glide is really nice to use as well: https://github.com/bumptech/glide